# Bad file descriptor error while sending from server - python

Tags: python, networking, text, python-3.x

Hi I can't figure out why this error happens. I've put in print statements and did a test script to try and isolate the problem and I just can't figure out why it doesn't work.

```
s = None
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC,
                          socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE):
    af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    print ('Listening on', sa)
    try:
        s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    except socket.error as msg:
        s = None
        continue
    try:
        s.bind(sa)
        s.listen(1)
    except socket.error as msg:
        s.close()
        s = None
        continue
    break
if s is None:
    print ('could not open socket')
    sys.exit(1)

def handler(signum, frame):
    s.close()
    sys.exit(1)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

while True:
    print('Waiting for connection...')
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print ('Connection from', addr)
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data: 
            break
        print ('data: ' + data.decode('utf-8'))
        filetoOpen = data.decode('utf-8')
        print('filetoOpen: ' + filetoOpen)

        with open (filetoOpen, 'r') as myfile:
            contents=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

        print('about to send :\n' + contents)
        conn.send(contents.encode('utf-8'))

        myfile.close()
        conn.close()

s.close()
sys.exit()
```

When I run it I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 67, in <module>
    data = conn.recv(1024)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I've tried messing around with it, saving the info to variables first, googling it and looking around online, I did a test script that just had in it and

```
with open ('/u/students/dzhelabori/NWEN241/sample2.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    contents=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

print(contents)
myfile.close()
```

which works fine and prints the file!
So the error happens when I try to just send the text across the network... but why does it say bad file descriptor and what should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the connection:

```
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    # ...
    conn.close()
```

After the first iteration of this loop, the connection is closed. Then the next iteration, you're trying to `recv` from a closed connection.

If, at that point, you're done with the connection, then why is it in a `while True` loop?